# Create a Power BI measure to sum a column where another column meets a requirement

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to DAX and I'm trying to do something that would be really simple in Excel!

Using data from the same table, I'm trying to add a measure, that calculates my 'TargetCost' column where the 'NameUnit' is '1111'.

if **nameunit** = **1111** then sum the **target cost**

In excel the formula would be:

=sumif(**nameunit**,**"1111"**,**targetcost**)

How do I write this into a measure in DAX please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[targetcost]),
    'Table'[nameunit] = "1111"
)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax

Comment: Thank you Peter. And how would I do this if I wanted to do exactly the same but to EXCLUDE everything that is "1111" please? 
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[targetcost]),
    'Table'[nameunit] **ISNOT** "1111"
)

***Update: Would it be <> instead of =? ***

Valid question for others, so will leave the comment in!